# Why isn't the MySQL Profiler working for me?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to analyse my database but I can't get profiler to work.  According to the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) it should be available since MySQL 5.0.37 and turning it on is as simple as executing the following statement

```
mysql> set profiling=1; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

However when I try it, I'm get this error: ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'profiling'

I'm using a more recent version of MySQL so I'm assuming that profiler should be available.

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------------------------+
| version()                   |
+-----------------------------+
| 5.1.22-rc-Debian_2~ppa5-log | 
+-----------------------------+
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that - according to this [discussion on mysql.com](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28288) - newer versions (Community Server) don't include the profiler.

If you execute

```
 select @@version;  
 show variables;
```

is there "profiling" in the output?

Comment: Bad news for me, you're right.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Also check exist of table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING. In that table going profiling information.